# How do I create a python script such that it sends an email when csv files in a directory has not updated in the last 24 hours?

Tags: python, string, operating-system, glob, smtplib

I am new to python and trying to understanding how to automate stuff. I have a folder in which 5 csv files get updated daily, however sometimes one of them or two dont on particular days. Im having to manually check this folder. Instead I want to automate this in such a way that if a csv file does not update in the last 24hours, It can send an email to myself alerting me of this.

My code:

```
import datetime
import glob
import os
import smtplib
import string
 
now  = datetime.datetime.today() #Get current date

list_of_files = glob.glob('c:/Python/*.csv') # * means all if need specific format then *.csv
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime) #get latest file created in folder

newestFileCreationDate = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(latest_file)) # get creation datetime of last file

dif = (now - newestFileCreationDate) #calculating days between actual date and last creation date

logFile = "c:/Python/log.log" #defining a log file

def checkFolder(dif, now, logFile):
    if dif > datetime.timedelta(days = 1): #Check if difference between today and last created file is greater than 1 days
        
        HOST = "12.55.13.12" #This must be your smtp server ip
        SUBJECT = "Alert! At least 1 day wthout a new file in folder xxxxxxx"
        TO = "xx.t@gmail.com"
        FROM = "xx.t@gmail.com"
        text = "%s - The oldest file in folder it's %s old " %(now, dif) 
        BODY = string.join((
            "From: %s" % FROM,
            "To: %s" % TO,
            "Subject: %s" % SUBJECT ,
            "",
            text
            ), "\r\n")
        server = smtplib.SMTP(HOST)
        server.sendmail(FROM, [TO], BODY)
        server.quit()
        
        file = open(logFile,"a") #Open log file in append mode
 
        file.write("%s - [WARNING] The oldest file in folder it's %s old \n" %(now, dif)) #Write a log
 
        file.close() 
        
    else : # If difference between today and last creation file is less than 1 days
                
        file = open(logFile,"a")  #Open log file in append mode
 
        file.write("%s - [OK] The oldest file in folder it's %s old \n" %(now, dif)) #write a log
 
        file.close() 

checkFolder(dif,now,logFile) #Call function and pass 3 arguments defined before
```

However, this does not run without error and I just want to be notified by mail of those files in the folder that havent been updated. even if it is one of out 5 files of them or 5 out of 5 that havent updated.

Answer (score 3):

Use pure python and concise way

```
import hashlib
import glob
import json
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
import time
import schedule #pip install schedule
hasher = hashlib.md5()
size = 65536 #to read large files in chunks 
list_of_files = glob.glob('./*.csv') #absolute path for crontab
```

Part 1) Run this script first then comment it out. It will create a json file with hashes of your files.

```
first_hashes = {}
for x in list_of_files:

    with open(x, 'rb') as f:
        buf = f.read(size)
        while len(buf) > 0:
            hasher.update(buf)
            buf = f.read(size)
            first_hashes[x] = hasher.hexdigest()

with open('hash.json', 'w') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(first_hashes, indent=2))
```

Now comment it out or even delete it.

Part 2) Automation script:

```
def send_email():


    check_hash = {} #Contain hashes that have not changed
    
    with open('hash.json') as f: #absolute path for crontab
         data = json.load(f)

    for x in list_of_files:

        with open(x, 'rb') as f:
            buf = f.read(size)
            while len(buf) > 0:
                hasher.update(buf)
                buf = f.read(size)
                new_hash = hasher.hexdigest()
                #if a hash match with one in data, that file has not changed
                if new_hash in data.values():
                    check_hash[x] = new_hash
                data[x] = new_hash


    #update our hashes
    with open('hash.json', 'w') as file:  #absolute path for crontab
         file.write(json.dumps(data, indent=2))

    if len(check_hash) > 0: #check if there's anything in check_hash

        filename="check_hash.txt" #absolute path for crontab

        #write to a text file named "check_hash.txt"
        with open(filename, 'w') as f: #absolute path for crontab
            f.write(json.dumps(check_hash, indent=2))

        
        # for gmail smtp setup watch youtu.be/JRCJ6RtE3xU 
        EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'SMTPAddress@gmail.com' 
        EMAIL_PASSWORD = 'SMTPPassWord'

        msg = EmailMessage()

        msg['Subject'] = 'Unupdated files'
        msg['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS
        msg['To'] = 'receive@gmail.com'
        msg.set_content('These file(s) did not update:')
        msg.add_attachment(open(filename, "r").read(), filename=filename)



        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
            smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
            smtp.send_message(msg)
 

#for faster testing check other options here github.com/dbader/schedule
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(send_email) 
while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

**EDIT:** If you restart your pc, you will need to run this file again to restart schedule, to avoid that, you can use crontab as follows (learn how from youtu.be/j-KgGVbyU08):

```
# mm hh DOM MON DOW command 
30 10 * * *  python3 path-to-file/email-script.py #Linux
30 10 * * *  python path-to-file/email-script.py #Windows
```

This will run the script everyday at 10:30 AM IF the pc is ON at that time. For faster testing (run every 1 minute) use:

```
* * * * *  python3 path-to-file/email-script.py
```

**NOTE:** If you gonna use crontab, you MUST use absolute path for all file references and replace

```
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(send_email) 
while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    send_email()
```

Tested and it's working great!

Comment: Hi Field Boy, thanks for your answer. where do I mention the smtp server name? also what do you mean by email_password.What needs to go there? Something I need to create or a password that already exists? I ran the above script but havent received an output or email. it is still running after 5 minutes

Comment: Gmail SMTP: Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security, Enable 2-step-verification, after it's enabled just below it click on"App Passwords", click on "Select app", and select "Other", Type in the name you want and click GENERATE. The password it will generate is the EMAIL_PASSWORD. If this not clear, watch this video https://youtu.be/JRCJ6RtE3xU

Comment: If you still having problems, let me know, be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Granted I don't know CSV but I would import time and using the format and time. Sleep function create a timer. What's good about time module is that you can configure it to set a value to a variable after time is up. SO maybe if you do that and put into an if statement, when the variable reaches a value, send the email.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of something like this?

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import smtplib
import textwrap

def send_email_failure():
    SERVER = "12.55.13.12" #This must be your smtp server ip
    SUBJECT = "Alert! At least 1 day without a new file in folder xxxxxxx"
    TO = "xx.t@gmail.com"
    FROM = "xx.t@gmail.com"
    TEXT = "%s - The oldest file in folder it's %sh old " %(datetime.now(), oldest_time_hour)
    """this is some test documentation in the function"""
    message = textwrap.dedent("""\
        From: %s
        To: %s
        Subject: %s
        %s
        """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT))
    print(message)
    # Send the mail
    server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.quit()
    

def save_log(logFile, ok_or_failure, time_now, delta):
  file = open(logFile,"a") #Open log file in append mode
  if ok_or_failure != 'ok':
    file.write("%s - [WARNING] The oldest file in folder it's %s old \n" %(time_now, delta)) 
  else:
    file.write("%s - [OK] The oldest file in folder it's %s old \n" %(time_now, delta)) 
  file.close() 



def check_file(filename):
  print(filename)
  if filename.endswith('.csv'):
    print('csv')
    try:
        mtime = os.path.getmtime(filename) # get modified time
    except OSError:
        mtime = 0
    last_modified_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(mtime)
    tdelta = datetime.now() - last_modified_date
    hours =  tdelta.seconds // 3600 # convert to hours
    return hours
  else:
    return 0


# we check what files are in the dir 'files' 
# and their modification time
oldest_time_hour = 0
for path, dirs, files in os.walk('./files'): # this need to be modified by case
  for file in files:
      # get each file time of modification
    time = check_file(path+'/'+file)
    if time > 0:
        # save the oldest time
      if time > oldest_time_hour:
        oldest_time_hour = time
    
# if it is older that 24h
if oldest_time_hour > 24:
  save_log('log.log', 'failure', datetime.now(), oldest_time_hour)
  send_email_failure()
else:
  save_log('log.log', 'ok', datetime.now(), oldest_time_hour)
```

also you will need an end-less loop to run the python script or a chronjob to run this python script every hour or so

Comment: I will be setting up a task scheduler. To give you an example of what I am trying to do. Lets say you have created a chronjob that runs multiple python apps everyday and creates output csv files that gets saved in a folder everyday. For some reason there is a failure and the file doesnt update in the folder. I want to send an email notification that lets me know which specific file has not updated in the directory without me having to check the folder manually.

Comment: The best approach would actually be to check where this possible failure may happen (in a try -> catch) and in that case send an email + log as it would be instantaneously of course if you could edit those python apps. But i believe this script will also work. If it does not fit your use case let me know so i can try to edit it

Comment: Im not entirely sure what I need to include in the line where you have given #the call to send email function should go here and the next line #the call to save_log. Is it ok with you if you could  paste from my code in your solution so I know exactly what you are referring to

Comment: Ok, i updated the code can you give it a look?

Comment: I am receiving an error from os import walk
_, _, filenames = next(walk('./files'))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-ff1a1c9da780>", line 2, in <module>
    _, _, filenames = next(walk('./files'))

StopIteration

Comment: Ok, now i also fixed that. Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi Andi, thank you for fixing it. Im about to mark this answer correct, but just one question, how do I run this to only catch csv type files that havent updated in the folder?

Comment: Modified the file to reflect that, i added `string.endswith('.csv')`

Comment: Hi Andi, I ran this code and it run without errors however, in the final output it only displayed the files that are part of the folder. It did not display modified time, I also did not receive any email after I mentioned mine in the "To". Am i missing something?

Comment: Hi, those messages are only for debug purposes. You should first check that the log.log file has the necessary logs, and that files older than 24h exist. If the logs are correct (meaning that there is a file older than 24h) we can check the email thingy, but most probably a config problem. Did you get the emails in your try?

Comment: I havent received emails. No csv files were added nor were any current csv files modified in that folder which is exactly when i need an email alert that none of those files were updated. Where do I find the log file? Would it be saved in the same path as the folder? if so there is no log file even after I ran all the lines of codes successfully

Comment: The log file is located where this|your python script is located. Also what kind of email provider do you have so we can setup the mail sending more easily.

Comment: I checked the log file it says" 2021-02-09 16:37:33.471789 - [OK] The oldest file in folder it's 21 old" not sure what that means

Answer (score 0):

Why are you checking the last_modified_date? I suggest you to check the modification of the file with md5 checksum.
My Idea is, if you have following files :

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
file4.csv
file5.csv
```

You can check their md5 checksum and write the result + DateTime into a file next to the original file. like following :

```
file1.csv
file1.csv_checksum
```

**Content of file1.csv_checksum**

timestamp,checksum

```
1612820511,d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

you can check md5 of a file with following code:

```py
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.md5(open('filename.exe','rb').read()).hexdigest()
```

then you can check the result with the provided one in the checksum file ( and if the checksum file does not exist, just create it for the first time )

I think you can easily handle it with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

At first i started with a task scheduler decorator which will enable you to poll a directory for a fixed delay:

```
import time
import functools


def scheduled(fixed_delay):
    def decorator_scheduled(func):
        functools.wraps(func)

        def wrapper_schedule(*args, **kwargs):
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            self = args[0]
            delay = getattr(self, fixed_delay)
            time.sleep(delay)
            return result
        return wrapper_schedule
    return decorator_scheduled
```

Saved it as a seperate module named *task_scheduler.py*.
I will use it in my file watcher:

```
import os
from task_scheduler import scheduled
import smtplib, ssl

class FileWatcher:
    def __init__(self, 
                 files_path='./myFiles',
                 extension='.csv',
                 poll_delay=2):
        self.files_path = files_path
        self.extension = extension
        self.poll_delay = poll_delay

    def notify_host_on_nonchange(self, file_path):
        port = 465  
        smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
        sender_email = "sender@gmail.com" 
        receiver_email = "receiver@gmail.com"  
        password = "Your password here" #You may want to read it from file 
        message = f"No change in file: {file_path} for 24 hurs!"

        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
            server.login(sender_email, password)
            server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)

    def watch(self):
        try:
            while True:
                self.poll_()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            log.debug('Polling interrupted by user.')

    @scheduled("poll_delay")
    def poll_(self,):
        for f in os.listdir(self.files_path):
            full_path = os.path.join(self.files_path, f)
            path_stat = os.stat(full_path)
            _, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
            ctime = path_stat.st_ctime
            diff = time.time() - ctime/3600
            if diff<=24 or not S_ISREG(path_stat.st_mode) or str(file_ext) != self.extension:
                continue
            self.notify_host_on_nonchange(full_path)
            


if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_listener = FileWatcher()
    file_listener.watch()
```

Above class defines a poll_ function which benefits from [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html) module to check the modification time. If modification time smaller than or equal to 24 or the file is not a regular file (means that it is a directory) or it does not have the extension you look for polling will skip it, otherwise calls the notify function to send e-mail. It uses the [gmail smtp server example](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/) but you can change it as appropriate for your environment. Watch function is a wrapper for continous polling.

This class is adapted from my machine learning model watcher and loader, you can access that version and project from [my github](https://github.com/artuncF/Simple-Generic-ML-Model-Server). For further explanation about decorator and script you can check out [my medium post](https://towardsdatascience.com/serving-machine-learning-models-from-python-bd8c43fb61d5).

Comment: thank you @artunc just wanted to know is the password something that i can create myself or is it an already existing smtp password that i need to look for

Comment: I get the error

AttributeError: 'FileWatcher' object has no attribute 'pmml_path'

Comment: Hello i edited the code now you shouldn't see an AttributeError.

Comment: For gmail you can use your own account usernam and password; however, you should turn-off google's safety feature from https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps. I suggest you to create another account and use its username and password just for this purpose.